# [quasar][capacitor] No external IP detected. Can't run without one

Tags: android, linux, vue.js, capacitor, quasar-framework

I am working on a quasar project for a mobile app using capacitor.

I used to run the app on my phone with the hot-reload module with `quasar dev -m capacitor -T android`. But since a few days ago, for some reason, I am getting this error : `App • ⚠️  No external IP detected. Can't run without one. Manually specify one?`.

I tried removing the src-capacitor folder, rolling back to a version of the project that I know was working, re-installing android studio. But none of these worked.

Additionnal information : I can launch the app on my phone from android studio but I get a white screen asking me to launch the app with quasar dev, the phone is pingabble from the computer and vice-versa, adb devices finds the phone.

I think that the issue is with quasar not finding how to open android studio as the command should open android studio with or without a phone attached.

Output from `quasar info` :

```
Operating System - Linux(5.17.6-artix1-1) - linux/x64
NodeJs - 18.1.0

Global packages
  NPM - 8.5.5
  yarn - 1.22.18
  @quasar/cli - 1.3.2
  @quasar/icongenie - Not installed
  cordova - 11.0.0

Important local packages
  quasar - 2.6.6 -- Build high-performance VueJS user interfaces (SPA, PWA, SSR, Mobile and Desktop) in record time
  @quasar/app - 3.3.3 -- Quasar Framework local CLI
  @quasar/extras - 1.13.6 -- Quasar Framework fonts, icons and animations
  eslint-plugin-quasar - Not installed
  vue - 3.2.33 -- The progressive JavaScript framework for building modern web UI.
  vue-router - 4.0.15
  vuex - Not installed
  electron - 12.2.3 -- Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS
  electron-packager - Not installed
  electron-builder - Not installed
  @babel/core - 7.17.10 -- Babel compiler core.
  webpack - 5.72.1 -- Packs CommonJs/AMD modules for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand. Support loaders to preprocess files, i.e. json, jsx, es7, css, less, ... and your custom stuff.
  webpack-dev-server - 4.7.4 -- Serves a webpack app. Updates the browser on changes.
  workbox-webpack-plugin - 6.4.2 -- A plugin for your Webpack build process, helping you generate a manifest of local files that workbox-sw should precache.
  register-service-worker - 1.7.2 -- Script for registering service worker, with hooks
  typescript - 4.5.5 -- TypeScript is a language for application scale JavaScript development
  @capacitor/core - 2.5.0 -- Capacitor: cross-platform mobile apps with the web
  @capacitor/cli - 2.5.0 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/android - 3.4.1 -- Capacitor: Cross-platform apps with JavaScript and the web
  @capacitor/ios - Not installed

Quasar App Extensions
  *None installed*

Networking
  Host - artix
```

Comment: I specified the private ip address of my computer with `-H 192.168.1.222` and it now works. But I have no idea why I need to specify it while it was working without it before